# Using spring Initializer Created a project dependency Spring web, Devtool, Actuator, Spring security getting error in POM.XML unknown

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

POM.XML giving unknown error

Using spring initializr created project

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.8.RELEASE
         
    
    com.boot.secury
    bootsecurity
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    bootsecurity
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Spring boot 2.1.8

Comment: Can you please add more details on what error you are getting ?

Comment: In eclipse Problems tab showing Unknown error in pom.xml line no 1